# CSS wildcard for article id's

Tags: css, wildcard

Can I use a wildcard * for article ids instead of:

```
article#post-100 {background-color: #bcd8d0;}
article#post-99 {background-color: #bcd8d0;}
article#post-98 {background-color: #bcd8d0;}
```

and so on...

Thank you.

Comment: in addtion to the duplicate you can simply do this `article {}` and will target all the article

Comment: Thank you, @TemaniAfif!!

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you help me with my other question? "Why am I getting syntax error for prepared statement" on stackexchange, please? ty